# How to create registry key windows 7 / windows 8 C#

Tags: c#, registry

I am using this code below

It runs without any error but i don't see any registry key is created

What may be the error ?

```
 Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true)
            .SetValue("OpenInBrowser.exe", 10000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I want webbrowser object to use internet explorer

Ok i see that it creates at Wow6432Node

How can i also create it at regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is forced to run in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit operating system so it creates the key in the wrong location.  Wow6432Node is the root of the keys visible to 32-bit processes.

By far the simplest fix is to change the Platform target setting on your EXE project to AnyCPU (turn off Prefer 32-bit on VS2012+).  RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() is next.